# Singleton class and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

Suppose I have the following singleton base class:

```
template <class Derived>
class Singleton
{
  public:

    inline static Derived* get();                       

  protected:

    Singleton();                                  
    ~Singleton();                                     
    static std::unique_ptr<Derived> _uptr;                

  private:

    Singleton(const Singleton&);                          
    Singleton & operator = (const Singleton&);             
};

// Initialize the singleton object.
template <class Derived>
std::unique_ptr<Derived> Singleton<Derived>::_uptr = nullptr;

// Constructor
template <class Derived>
Singleton<Derived>::Singleton() {
}

// Constructor
template <class Derived>
Singleton<Derived>::~Singleton() {
}

// Function: get
template <class Derived>
inline Derived* Singleton<Derived>::get() {
  if(_uptr != nullptr) return _uptr.get();
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> tmp(new Derived());
  _uptr = std::move(tmp);
  return _uptr.get();
}
```

And I have the following derived classes:

```
class Foo : public Singleton <Foo> {
  public:
    int value;     
}

int main() {
  Foo A;
  Foo B;
  A.value = 1;
  B.value = 2;
  A.get()->value = 3;
  cout << A.value << endl;  // we get 1
  cout << B.value << endl;  // we get 2
  cout << A.get()->value() << " " << B.get()->value() << endl;  // we get 3
}
```

I am wondering why the three methods give completely different outputs on `value`. Shouldn't A and B return the same value as they inherit the same singleton base? To be more specific, I wanna implement a class that has global scope and will be initiated only once.

Comment: _`Foo A;
  Foo B;`_ A Singleton where you have 2 instances actually, isn't that contradictory? I think you have some serious misconceptions here. You should actually prevent, that more than **a single** instance of that class can be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to explicitely delete the (automatically created) default constructors and assignment operators in your derived Singleton classes to prohibit instantiation of more than one instance:

```
class Foo : public Singleton <Foo> {
public:
    int value;
    delete Foo();
    delete Foo(const Foo&);
    delete Foo& operator(const Foo&);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the singleton-pattern.

It is called singleton because only one instance is allowed. This is done by making the constructor private so that you can only create the instance via the get-function.

Consequently `Foo A` and `Foo B` would be illegal.

You get wrong values because you create 3 instances - that is not a singleton.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Foo` has a member variable `int value`, and also a static member variable `std::unique_ptr<Foo> _uptr`.

```
A.value = 1;        // now A.value == 1 and _uptr == nullptr
B.value = 2;        // now B.value == 2 and _uptr == nullptr
A.get()->value = 3; // now _uptr points to a Foo whose value is 3
```

There are three Foos, and three values.